# dataTables - Adicionar e preservar classe CSS à última coluna de cada linha

Tags: jquery, jquery-datatables

Para adicionar uma classe de CSS à última coluna de cada linha, utilizo o seguinte método:

```
var dataTablesOptions = {
  'columnDefs': [
    { targets: -1, className: 'text-center' }
  ],
  // ...
};

$('#minhaTabela').DataTable( dataTablesOptions );
```

O problema é que após execução de qualquer ação cujos dados sejam provenientes do servidor, a última `<td/>` perde a classe de CSS.

#### Como preservar a classe de CSS mesmo após chamadas Ajax ?

Answer (score 2):

[`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) é uma opção que permite definir propriedades na inicialização do plugIn dataTables, mas não é relida após ocorrerem atualizações à tabela.

Para que, mesmo após chamadas Ajax a classe de CSS ou outra propriedades sejam preservadas, deverás fazer uso da opção [`createdRow`](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html), cuja mesma é executada sempre que uma linha é criada na tabela, seja na inicialização, seja após manipulação da tabela:

```
var dataTablesOptions = {
  'createdRow': function ( row, data, index ) {
    $(row).find('td:last-child').addClass('text-center');
  },
  // ...
}

$('#minhaTabela').DataTable( dataTablesOptions );
```